# Internet explorer 10 download for windows server 2008 R2

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-server-2008-r2, internet-explorer-10

Im trying to download Internet Explorer 10 for Windows 2008R2 but the Microsoft downloads page found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/internet-explorer.aspx) lists everything **but** IE10.

The closest I can find is an update for IE10 found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39240)

Does anyone know where I can find a legitimate copy of IE10? Id rather not use torrents or similar sites and prefer to use an official Microsoft copy.

Comment: "Officially" Microsoft dropped IE10 and replaced it with 11, so why not just use IE11?